# Change Text in Vb.net DropDownStyle Combobox after an item is selected

Tags: vb.net

How would I change the displayed text in a combobox that is a dropdownstyle after something  is selected in vb.net? For example, if the user picks "dog" from the list, it will display a number 1 instead of dog.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways to do this. Either way, you must have some relationship between the animal name and id. So here's a basic class

```
Public Class Animal
    Public Sub New(id As Integer, name As String)
        Me.Name = name
        Me.ID = id
    End Sub
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

keep a list of Animal

```
Private animals As List(Of Animal)
```

and populate it

```
animals = New List(Of Animal)()
animals.Add(New Animal(1, "Dog"))
animals.Add(New Animal(2, "Cat"))
animals.Add(New Animal(3, "Fish"))
```

**Two ways I mentioned**

1. Using this list as a DataSource

```
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
ComboBox1.DataSource = animals
```

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1?.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() ComboBox1.Text = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedValue, Integer).ToString())
    End If
End Sub
```

2. Populating the ComboBox with string names

You do still need the class to keep a relationship between animal name and id

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(animals.Select(Function(a) a.Name).ToArray())
```

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1?.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() ComboBox1.Text = animals.SingleOrDefault(Function(a) a.Name = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())?.ID.ToString())
    End If
End Sub
```

Both methods will produce the same result, but I would say the DataSource is nicer since you can just get the ComboBox1.SelectedValue as an Animal, and retrieve either the Name or ID simply, instead of using some LINQ to extract the ID in the second case.

[image]

Comment: I think you are supposed to set the display and value before the datasource. I finally found the reason why and promptly forgot it. Remember, I'm old.

Comment: @Mary right, yes, I have read that too but maybe I don't always do it because the negative implication doesn't seem to manifest enough to remind me the reason not to do it! I edited anyway thanks!